# $t^l\leq \Phi(t)+1,\forall t\geq1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I have that $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$  is a continuous, increasing and convex function such that 
$$t^l\Phi(1)\leq \Phi(t)\leq t^m \Phi(1), \;\;\forall t\geq1$$ where $1<l<m$.

and $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}=0~\text{and}~\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}=+\infty.$

I want to prove that $$t^l\leq \Phi(t)+1,\;\;\forall t\geq1$$

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take $l = 2$, $m = 3$ and $\Phi(t) = \frac12 \, t^2$. It is clear that your assumptions are satisfied. However, with $t = 2$ you get
$$4 = t^2 \not\le \Phi(t) + 1 = \frac12 \, 2^2 + 1 = 3.$$